# How to do MapReduce on Riak with Erlang to get even values from all the keys storing the numbers from 1 to 1000

Tags: erlang, riak, erlang-shell

I am trying to do mapreduce on Riak with Erlang. I am having data like the following:

```
Bucket = "Numbers"
{Keys,values} = {Random key,1},{Random key,2}........{Random key,1000}.
```

Now, I am storing 1000 values from 1 to 1000, where all the keys are autogenerated by the term undefined given as a parameter, so all the keys will have values starting from 1 to 1000.

So I want the data from only the values that are even numbers. Using mapreduce, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would construct phase functions as described in http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/mapreduce/

One possible map function:

```
Mapfun = fun(Object, _KeyData, _Arg) ->
    %% get the object value, convert to integer and check if even
    Value = list_to_integer(binary_to_term(riak_object:get_value(Object))),
    case Value rem 2 of
      0 -> [Value];
      1 -> []
    end
end.
```

Although you probably want to not completely fail in the event you encounter a sibling:

```
Mapfun = fun(Object, _KeyData, _Arg) ->
    Values = riak_object:get_values(Object),
    case length(Values) of        %% checking for siblings
      1 ->                   %% only 1 value == no siblings
         I = list_to_integer(binary_to_term(hd(Values))),
         case I rem 2 of
            0 -> [I];    %% value is even
            1 -> []          %% value is odd
         end;
      _ -> []                %% What should happen with siblings?
    end
end.
```

There may also be other cases you need to either prevent or check for: the value containing non-numeric characters, empty value, deleted values(tombsones), just to name a few.

Edit:
A word of caution:  Doing a full-bucket MapReduce job will require Riak to read every value from the disk, this could cause extreme latency and timeout on a sizeable data set.  Probably not something you want to do in production.

---

A full example of peforming MapReduce (limited to the numbers 1 to 200 for space considerations):

Assuming that you have cloned and built the [riak-erlang-client](https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client)
Using the second Mapfun from above

```
erl -pa {path-to-riak-erlang-client}/ebin
```

Define a reduce function to sort the list

```
Reducefun = fun(List,_) -> 
    lists:sort(List) 
end.
```

Attach to the local Riak server

```
{ok, Pid} = riakc_pb_socket:start_link("127.0.0.1", 8087).
```

Generate some test data

```
[ riakc_pb_socket:put(
                  Pid,
                  riakc_obj:new(
                            <<"numbers">>,
                            list_to_binary("Key" ++ V),V
                            )
                  ) || V <- [ integer_to_list(Itr) || Itr <- lists:seq(1,200)]],
```

The function to perform a MapReduce with this client is
`mapred(pid(), mapred_inputs(), [mapred_queryterm()])`

The `mapred_queryterm` is a list of phase specification of the form `{Type, FunTerm, Arg, Keep}` as defined in the [readme](https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client/blob/master/README.md#mapreduce).  For this example, there are 2 phases:

- a map phase that selects only even numbers
  `{map, Mapfun, none, true}`
- a reduce phase that sorts the result
  `{reduce, Reducefun, none, true}`

Perform the MapReduce query

```
{ok,Results} = riakc_pb_socket:mapred(
                              Pid,  %% The socket pid from above
                              <<"numbers">>,  %% Input is the bucket 
                              [{map,{qfun,Mapfun},none,true},
                              {reduce,{qfun,Reducefun},none,true}]
                                     ),
```

`Results` will be a list of `[{_Phase Index_, _Phase Output_}]` with a separate entry for each phase for which `Keep` was true, in this example both phases are marked keep, so in this example `Results` will be
`[{0,[_map phase result_]},{1,[_reduce phase result_]}]`

Print out the result of each phase:

```
[ io:format("MapReduce Result of phase ~p:~n~P~n",[P,Result,500]) 
                || {P,Result} <- Results ].
```

When I ran this, my output was:

```
MapReduce Result of phase 0:
[182,132,174,128,8,146,18,168,70,98,186,118,50,28,22,112,82,160,114,106,12,26,
 124,14,194,64,122,144,172,96,126,162,58,170,108,44,90,104,6,196,40,154,94,
 120,76,48,150,52,4,62,140,178,2,142,100,166,192,66,16,36,38,88,102,68,34,32,
 30,164,110,42,92,138,86,54,152,116,156,72,134,200,148,46,10,176,198,84,56,78,
 130,136,74,190,158,24,184,180,80,60,20,188]
MapReduce Result of phase 1:
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,
 56,58,60,62,64,66,68,70,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,102,
 104,106,108,110,112,114,116,118,120,122,124,126,128,130,132,134,136,138,140,
 142,144,146,148,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,168,170,172,174,176,178,
 180,182,184,186,188,190,192,194,196,198,200]
[ok,ok]
```

Comment: I have done the first step of what you said , i am getting            '#Fun<erl_eval.18.82930912>' , what does it mean

Comment: what should i give parameters i mean, to the  'Mapfun(X,Y,Z)'  @joe

Comment: You don't call it directly, you pass the function as part of your MapReduce call.  How you do that will depend on what client you are using.  There are some examples on Basho's website.

Comment: How to write it, that i dont know

Comment: Assuming you are using the Erlang client, the mapreduce section of the [readme](https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client/blob/master/README.md#mapreduce) should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: your example really helped me a lot @Joe . Now i understood how to write the mapreduce queries in erlang. really helped me a lot, thank you. and one more doubt..what if the data is like {'name':'george','age':24},{'name':'krish','age':26},{..},{..}. In the get_value(object) part if i want only the age then should i write like get_value(object.age) ..? am i right , if wrong please correct me

Comment: Erlang doesn't handle json natively.  `binary_to_term(riak_object:get_value(Object))` will give you back exactly what you stored.  So if you store your values as datatypes Erlang can process, the map/reduce functions can do whatever you like with the value.

Comment: my function is :  Mapf  = fun(Object,_,_) -> [X || X <- binary_to_term(riakc_obj:get_value(Object))] end. i am calling the mapreduce as {ok, [{X}]} = riakc_pb_socket:mapred(Pid,<<"test">>,[{map,{qmap,Mapf},none,true}]). But, i am getting error called ** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,
                                                       <<"Phase 0: The PhaseSpec part of the argument for riak_kv_mrc_map must be of one of the following forms:\n   {m"...>>}

Comment: now i tried a new data. Object = riakc_obj:new(<<"test_age">>, <<"test1">>, <<"gopi & 1">>). Mapf = fun(Obj,_,_) -> [{I,1}|| I <- binary_to_term(riak_object:get_value(Object))] end. 
{ok, [{0,[R]}]} = riakc_pb_socket:mapred(Pid,<<"test_age">>,[{map,{qfun,Mapf},none,true}])
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,<<"{\"phase\":0,\"error\":\"function_clause\",\"input\":\"{ok,{r_object,<<\\\"test_age\\\">>,<<\\\"test1\\\">>,[{r_content,{dict"...>>}

Comment: I think you meant to use `get_values`, the `get_value` function will throw an error if the object contains more than one value.  You also used `Obj` in the function header, but `Object` in the body.